# caching select count(*) results

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ehcache

Can the count results of named queries be cachced ? as far as I know, that caching is available only for objects that are instances of entities that you mention them in the ehcache.xml.

If I want to cache a named query that has a result of a number (count) or any data that are not mapped to an entity how can I do that ?

If it can be done , how dose that works while you dont have an @Id (a primary key for the result)